# HtmlUnit infinite loop when redirect link after the form submit is same as the one containing form

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to login to a web page https://online.firstdata.de/esp/concardis/ using HTMLunit library in Java. The thing is that this page contains a form inside a couple of iframes. The source of the iframe containing the form is https://online.firstdata.de/login/postlogin/UserDispatcher
. When a form is submitted then one of the redirect links before the next page is rendered is also the same link as mentioned above.
So, this creates an infinite loop when I use it from Java. However, when the login happens from the browser because the main source of the originating page was the link ending with /concardis the redirect link is not the same as this link and hence there is no infinite loop. How can I simulate this same behaviour from Java? Here is my code :

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);    
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());


    try{


        HtmlPage page1 = null;
        HtmlPage page2 = null;
        HtmlPage page3 = null;
         HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://online.firstdata.de/esp/concardis");




        List<FrameWindow> frames = page.getFrames();
        for (FrameWindow frame : frames) {
            if (frame.getFrameElement().getNameAttribute().equals("application")) {
                page1 = webClient.getPage(frame.getEnclosedPage().getUrl());
            }
        }

        List<FrameWindow> frames1 = page1.getFrames();
        for (FrameWindow frame : frames1) {
            if (frame.getFrameElement().getNameAttribute().equals("content")) {
                page2 = webClient.getPage(frame.getEnclosedPage().getUrl());
            }
        }

        List<FrameWindow> frames2 = page2.getFrames();
        for (FrameWindow frame : frames2) {
            if (frame.getFrameElement().getId().equals("loginFrame")) {
                page3 = webClient.getPage(frame.getFrameElement().getSrcAttribute());
            }
        }


        HtmlForm form = page3.getFormByName("loginForm");
        HtmlTextInput userName = form.getInputByName("j_username");
        HtmlPasswordInput password = form.getInputByName("j_password");

        userName.setValueAttribute("username");
        password.setValueAttribute("password");

        HtmlSubmitInput submit = form.getInputByName("Submit");

        submit.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but i'm not sure i got your problem right but....

1. HtmlUnit tries to mimic the browser as close as possible, if you are facing a difference you should open an issue
2. Without any credentials it is not possible to reproduce your case
3. HtmlUnit loads the content of iframes automatically - there is no need for all the webClient.getPage calls - maybe that is the root of the confusion

Have cleaned up your code a bit

```
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://online.firstdata.de/esp/concardis");

    HtmlPage page1 = null;
    List<FrameWindow> frames = page.getFrames();
    for (FrameWindow frame : frames) {
        if (frame.getFrameElement().getNameAttribute().equals("application")) {
            page1 = (HtmlPage) frame.getEnclosedPage();
            break;
        }
    }

    HtmlPage page2 = null;
    List<FrameWindow> frames1 = page1.getFrames();
    for (FrameWindow frame : frames1) {
        if (frame.getFrameElement().getNameAttribute().equals("content")) {
            page2 = (HtmlPage) frame.getEnclosedPage();
            break;
        }
    }

    HtmlPage page3 = null;
    List<FrameWindow> frames2 = page2.getFrames();
    for (FrameWindow frame : frames2) {
        if (frame.getFrameElement().getId().equals("loginFrame")) {
            page3 = (HtmlPage) frame.getEnclosedPage();
            break;
        }
    }

    HtmlForm form = page3.getFormByName("loginForm");
    HtmlTextInput userName = form.getInputByName("j_username");
    HtmlPasswordInput password = form.getInputByName("j_password");

    userName.type("username");
    password.type("password");

    HtmlSubmitInput submit = form.getInputByName("Submit");

    submit.click();
```

If it still not works please open an issue (but in this case we need some test credentials to reproduce your case)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I would like to explain the problem again in brief. In the page https://online.firstdata.de/esp/concardis/ there is a frameset which contains two frames. Inside one of the frames called application there is another frameset. Inside this frameset there is a frame called "Login.do". Inside this frame is an iframe with id "loginFrame" with src which is "https://online.firstdata.de/login/postlogin/UserDispatcher". This iframe in the body contains the login form. So, to access the login form I need to access all these frames. When i finally do submit.click.

Comment: The url of the page which does the submit has the url https://online.firstdata.de/login/postlogin/UserDispatcher. After the button is clicked the redirect happens and one of the redirect links is also https://online.firstdata.de/login/postlogin/UserDispatcher which creates an infinte loop and in java i get stack overflow error. HTMLUnit is definitely working fine as it is able to validate the username and password correctly. But redirect page after the login form is submitted has same url as the page which submits the form.It is similar to https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/367/

Comment: If it still differs from browses please open an HtmlUnit issue - and provide as many details (or even better a testcase) as you can.

Comment: Have checked this with HtmlUnit and it looks like HtmlUnit like the real browsers has a redirect limit; if this limit is reached, redirection will stop. There must be a different reason for your problems....

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried with your code. It now fails with read timeout exception. I tried to set the timeout webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(0); and then it keeps processing forever. Can you tell me where I can create an issue and give the credentials?

Comment: There is some description regarding issues here http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingBugs.html and here http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html. Regarding the password: i think you should send it via private mail (you can find my mail address in the list of developers htmlunit.sourceforge.net/team-list.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I think your solution worked. The server of the website was down when I had checked before. I tried just now and it worked. Also the response obtained after the submit button was clicked had the same url as the login page. So the response had to be parsed from inside the frames.